# React Native onesignal

Tags: react-native, onesignal

IM trying to use onesignal with react native. I linked everything on android and ios. Everything is working fine on ios but I get undefined is not an object (evaluating RNOneSignal.configure).

and I just added this line:     `OneSignal.configure({});`

Comment: Probably you did something wrong or skipped some steps while linking. How did you link exactly and on what platform are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

on the AppDelegate.m put the @synthesize oneSignal = _oneSignal; statement between the @implementation block and the @end block. I was putting it after @end and I was having the same problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my way the reason was this library was not linked correctly. Check this strings in file android/app/src/main/java/YOUR_APP_FOLDER/MainApplication.java:

```
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;
```

before first method and

```
new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage()
```

inside "return Arrays.asList("